# Create a function that return total Working days between two dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, calendar

I would like to create a function in SQL Server that would return the no of working days after checking the day from the dimension table dimcalender which has all the working days from 2020 up until 2040

My Code:

```
Create FUNCTION [udf_WorkingDays] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME
) 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TotalDays INT
    SET @StartDate = '2022/06/01'
    SET @EndDate = '2022/06/07'
    SET @TotalDays = 0
    --SET @TotalDays =(
    WHILE (@StartDate <= @EndDate)
    BEGIN
        sum(select WorkingDay
        FROM [XS].[dimCalendar]
        where [Date] >= @StartDate
        and [Date] <= @EndDate)

        set @StartDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @StartDate)
        --set @TotalDays = dss;)
    END;

    RETURN @TotalDays
END;
```

[dimCalendar] is where all UK working days are recorded.
WorkingDay is just a flag to say 0,1 (if its a working day or not.)
TotalDays is a variable that will have total no. of working days that will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
DECLARE @TotalDays INT
DECLARE @DDays INT
SET @StartDate = '2022/06/01'
SET @EndDate = '2022/06/06'
SET @TotalDays = 0

SET @TotalDays = (
    SELECT a.toti
    FROM (
        SELECT SUM(WorkingDay) AS toti
        FROM [dimCalendar]
        WHERE [Date] >= @StartDate
        AND [Date] <= @EndDate 
    ) AS a
)
RETURN @TotalDays;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?